# Error 'java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Read timed out' when the query has too much data :

Tags: sql-server, birt

Is BIRT has some size restriction?

I've a report that works well except if the report return 198,101 lines.

The query was successful in the SQL Server but when I run the report, I've an error : "Cannot load the report query : 208 errors occurred when generationg the report document for the report element with ID 228"

The element ID 228 is a table with the query I executed well in SQL Server.

The report works well if I have less data.

How can I fix this issue?

EDIT : in one log I found the error :

```
java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Read timed out
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.Statement.executeQuery(Statement.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.doExecuteQuery(OdaQuery.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaQuery.executeQuery(OdaQuery.java:433)
```

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried increasing the java heap with the `-Xmx` parameter?

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's not working, I tried 2048 and 3072